# How does Lebesgue integrals differ from Riemann integrals in terms of computations?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

So far I've understood that the framework to defining Lebesgue integrals is totally different from Riemann integrals. But, **how do the actual computations of integrals to differ?**

In Riemann integrals, I understand computation of an integral as, algebraically manipulating the integral till its in form where the expression inside the integrand is the derivative of something we know. So, when we say the amount of Lebesgue integrable functions are more, what are the new computations allowed to calculate their value?

Comment: One of the things that is newly allowed is "changing the value of the function on a set of Lebesgue measure zero".

Comment: In practice, the only way to evaluate a Lebesgue integral — unless you can apply some sort of dominated convergence limiting argument — is to evaluate a Riemann integral.

Comment: What about $\int_{[0,1]} D(x)dx$, where $D=\chi_{\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}}$?